# MYSQL SELECT with GROUP. Want to limit the number of returned elements in the GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-concat

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(counts) 
FROM devicedata 
GROUP BY hour
```

GROUP_CONCAT(counts) returns rows with differing numbers of elements.

IE: `24,54,67,44,78`  or `44,88,54`

I want to limit the number of elements returned, IE: `24,54,67` and not get `44,78`

The data table looks like this:

```
counts, hour
34,00
46,01
56,01
32,02
83,03 etc....
```

Comment: Bloody Hell, yes it does. Thanks

Comment: It's completely nonsensical to include `*` alongside an aggregating function. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX() works in the SQL box of phpmyAdmin but when I put the code in my program I get this ['0',],['1',],['2',],['3',] etc...  The data field is empty.  But in phpmyadmin I get this: ['0',65.,58.25,60.49,60.19,48.36,52.24,72.32,48.41,48.74,47.etc.

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING_INDEX() won't work because GROUP_CONCAT returns a string and SUBSTRING_INDEX() needs an array returned

So I wrote a quick string parser that counts "," and appends to a blank string.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to return a subset of the group.

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(counts), ',', 3)
FROM devicedata 
GROUP BY hour
```

That returns the first 3 fields in the comma-delimited list.

Comment: possibly `GROUP_CONCAT(counts order by counts)` or `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct counts order by counts)`   And in mariadb 10.3+, you can add a `limit 3` inside group_concat.